# Is there a PickList widget in GWT?

Tags: gwt, gwt-bootstrap

There is a [PickList widget](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/pickList.xhtml) in PrimeFaces JSF component library?

Does GWT (or any other GWT component library) has such a widget?

Comment: Nothing, i've heard of , you might have to create one for yourself. http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:listtolist

Comment: GXT has DualListView: http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:duallistfield

Comment: I think this can easyly be created by using CellLists. http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at SmartGWT's featured example on [Databound Dragging](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_db_dragging_featured_category). You can also view its source. But since gwt does not have such widget, the best solution is to create your own custom component with the help of [CellList](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList).

Comment: I was looking for the same thing and I couldn't find anything good so I made my own with `CellList`.

Comment: This answer looks useful since SmartGWT's widget provides what I am looking for. But, since I'm using gwt-bootstrap, switching to SmartGWT does not seem practical for my case.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to create my own PickList as it's easy and straightforward, below is what it looks like:

```
public abstract class PickList<T> extends Composite {
    //The renderer provide the flexibility for client class customize the cell
    public PickList(SafeHtmlRenderer<T> renderer) {
      ...
    }

    public void setCandidates(List<T> candidates, List<T> selected) {
       //todo
    }

    public List<T> getSelectedValues() {
       //todo
    }

    //Below two abstract method can facilitate getting values from view or rendering view from value
    protected abstract T fromIdentity(String identity);
    protected abstract String toIdentity(T value);
}
```